# sudo apt-get update gives 404 error "E: The repository 'http://ir.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu artful Release' no longer has a Release file."

Tags: apt, 17.10

When I try to use sudo apt-get update it gives me these errors :

```
E: The repository 'http://ir.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu artful Release' no longer has a Release file.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
E: The repository 'http://ir.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu artful-updates Release' no longer has a Release file.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
E: The repository 'http://ir.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu artful-backports Release' no longer has a Release file.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
E: The repository 'http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu yakkety Release' does not have a Release file.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
```

What's the problem and how can I fix it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems that the mirror you're using (http://ir.archive.ubuntu.com/) is not working.

There is usually a mirror per country, identified by the their [ISO two letter country code](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_3166-1_alpha-2), in your case **ir**.

The easiest way to fix your problem is to edit your `/etc/apt/sources.list` and replace `http://ir.archive.ubuntu.com/` by `http://SOME_OTHER_COUNTRY_CODE_HERE.archive.ubuntu.com/`

There are also other ubuntu mirrors listed [here](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+archivemirrors) with their status.

Comment: thanks that worked! 
1 question though
how can I add the mirrors listed here in my source.list file? replace http://ir.archive.ubuntu.come with them? or add them in the end?

Comment: you should replace them