# 403 error when running sudo apt update

Tags: apt, updates

I am new to Linux. I am trying to update Ubuntu (4.15.0-153). When I run `sudo apt-get update`, I get the following error:

```
Err:1 http://sg.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic InRelease
403 Forbidden [IP: 202.79.184.254 80]
Err:2 http://sg.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates InRelease
403 Forbidden [IP: 202.79.184.254 80]
Err:3 http://sg.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-backports InRelease
403 Forbidden [IP: 202.79.184.254 80]
Err:4 http://sg.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security InRelease
403 Forbidden [IP: 202.79.184.254 80]
Reading package lists... Done
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
E: The repository 'http://sg.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic InRelease' is no longer signed.
E: Failed to fetch http://sg.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/bionic/InRelease 403 Forbidden [IP: 202.79.184.254 80]
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
E: The repository 'http://sg.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates InRelease' is no longer signed.
E: Failed to fetch http://sg.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/bionic-updates/InRelease 403 Forbidden [IP: 202.79.184.254 80]
E: Failed to fetch http://sg.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/bionic-backports/InRelease 403 Forbidden [IP: 202.79.184.254 80]
E: The repository 'http://sg.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-backports InRelease' is no longer signed.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
E: Failed to fetch http://sg.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/bionic-security/InRelease 403 Forbidden [IP: 202.79.184.254 80]
E: The repository 'http://sg.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security InRelease' is no longer signed.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
```

Comment: Not 100% sure, but, change your apt repos. Not sure what apps this distro has in it since this is the first I've heard of it, but, that looks like an issue with the repo being used. Should be an app to change repos or maybe can use synaptic.

Comment: Are you running any proxy servers or firewalls? Is this a home pc or is it on your company network?
It sounds like you are behind a firewall that might be blocking you **Update**.
If you take that forbidden IP address and paist it in the browser it goes straight to a 403 forbidden page.
try changing your repos and see if that works

Comment: Hi Gerry, i have checked our Firewall, it is not being blocked.

Comment: Edit your repo to this http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/bionic/InRelease. all you do i take out the sg from sg.archive

Comment: Hi Amy, i'm not sure how to update the repos. Do you know the steps? Will try to look into how update it  and where to get the list of repos.

Comment: Do you know the steps to update the repos ? Will try to look into how update it and where to get the list of repos

Comment: I am running the ubuntu server and the repos file is /etc/apt/source.list. Look for tha address and just remove the sg and let us know if it works.

Comment: its working now. thanks to everyone. I edit the sources.list file as suggested by Gerry.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [sudo apt-get update gives 404 error "E: The repository 'http://ir.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu artful Release' no longer has a Release file."](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1019839/sudo-apt-get-update-gives-404-error-e-the-repository-http-ir-archive-ubuntu)

Comment: http://sg.archive.ubuntu.com/  seems down

Answer (score 0):

Try to change the download server from Software&Updates setting under Ubuntu Software. I did that and problem was solved.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

For me it's a problem with the Singapore server 'download.nus.edu/mirror/ubuntu'.

As @KorbanProyek mentionend, change the download server by:

- open **Software&Updates**
- open **Download from**
- scroll to **Singapore**
- select (for example) second entry

Answer (score 0):

You can try to switch your download location to Main Server instead of Server for Singapore. Then do sudo apt-get update again.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/F63QF.png)

source:

["apt update" failed with "403 Forbidden" error on Ubuntu 22.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1428227/apt-update-failed-with-403-forbidden-error-on-ubuntu-22-04)

Comment: doesn't work for me on any server. https://askubuntu.com/questions/1438508/403-error-forbidden-ip-apt-get-update-on-any-server