# 403 error forbidden IP: apt get update on main server

Tags: 20.04

I know this has been [already asked](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1428156/403-error-when-running-sudo-apt-update). Please merge the question if needed. I changed the server to Main server from UK server, still I am getting the 403 error.

```
╭─    ~                                               ✔  6s   base  
╰─ sudo apt upgrade 
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Calculating upgrade... Done
The following package was automatically installed and is no longer required:
  libxmlb1
Use 'sudo apt autoremove' to remove it.
Try Ubuntu Pro beta with a free personal subscription on up to 5 machines.
Learn more at https://ubuntu.com/pro
The following NEW packages will be installed
  libxmlb2
The following packages will be upgraded:
  containerd.io docker-ce docker-ce-cli docker-ce-rootless-extras
  docker-compose-plugin docker-scan-plugin fwupd gnome-software
  gnome-software-common gnome-software-plugin-flatpak
  gnome-software-plugin-snap google-chrome-stable grub-efi-amd64-bin
  grub-efi-amd64-signed libfwupd2 libfwupdplugin5 libnvidia-cfg1-515
  libnvidia-common-515 libnvidia-compute-515 libnvidia-compute-515:i386
  libnvidia-decode-515 libnvidia-decode-515:i386 libnvidia-encode-515
  libnvidia-encode-515:i386 libnvidia-extra-515 libnvidia-fbc1-515
  libnvidia-fbc1-515:i386 libnvidia-gl-515 libnvidia-gl-515:i386
  linux-firmware nvidia-compute-utils-515 nvidia-dkms-515 nvidia-driver-515
  nvidia-kernel-common-515 nvidia-kernel-source-515 nvidia-utils-515
  obs-studio snapd teamviewer tzdata xserver-xorg-video-nvidia-515
41 to upgrade, 1 to newly install, 0 to remove and 0 not to upgrade.
Need to get 87.8 MB/898 MB of archives.
After this operation, 51.1 MB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y
Err:1 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates/main amd64 libxmlb2 amd64 0.3.6-2build1~20.04.1
  403  Forbidden [IP: 185.125.190.39 80]
Err:2 http://ppa.launchpad.net/obsproject/obs-studio/ubuntu focal/main amd64 obs-studio amd64 28.1.0-0obsproject1~focal
  403  Forbidden [IP: 185.125.190.52 80]
Err:3 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates/main amd64 fwupd amd64 1.7.9-1~20.04.1
  403  Forbidden [IP: 185.125.190.39 80]
Err:4 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates/main amd64 libfwupdplugin5 amd64 1.7.9-1~20.04.1
  403  Forbidden [IP: 185.125.190.39 80]
Err:5 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates/main amd64 libfwupd2 amd64 1.7.9-1~20.04.1
  403  Forbidden [IP: 185.125.190.39 80]
Err:6 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates/main amd64 grub-efi-amd64-signed amd64 1.173.2~20.04.1+2.04-1ubuntu47.4
  403  Forbidden [IP: 185.125.190.39 80]
E: Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/libx/libxmlb/libxmlb2_0.3.6-2build1~20.04.1_amd64.deb  403  Forbidden [IP: 185.125.190.39 80]
E: Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/f/fwupd/fwupd_1.7.9-1~20.04.1_amd64.deb  403  Forbidden [IP: 185.125.190.39 80]
E: Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/f/fwupd/libfwupdplugin5_1.7.9-1~20.04.1_amd64.deb  403  Forbidden [IP: 185.125.190.39 80]
E: Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/f/fwupd/libfwupd2_1.7.9-1~20.04.1_amd64.deb  403  Forbidden [IP: 185.125.190.39 80]
E: Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/g/grub2-signed/grub-efi-amd64-signed_1.173.2~20.04.1+2.04-1ubuntu47.4_amd64.deb  403  Forbidden [IP: 185.125.190.39 80]
E: Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/obsproject/obs-studio/ubuntu/pool/main/o/obs-studio/obs-studio_28.1.0-0obsproject1~focal_amd64.deb  403  Forbidden [IP: 185.125.190.52 80]
E: Unable to fetch some archives, maybe run apt-get update or try with --fix-missing?
```

Comment: Your title says on any server. Here is the list you have tried them all? https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+archivemirrors

Comment: No but I tried the main and Uk server

Comment: Proxy on your system maybe?

Comment: May be. I am using my university's internet. But thereis no proxy settings from my side. How to check for proxy networks? BTW I can access these IPs from my web browser.

Comment: Okay, yiou can check in firefox https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/connection-settings-firefox

Comment: As I said no proxy settings from my side. I have asked my IT team, they said they haven't blocked anything except torrents.

Comment: Sorry no idea anymore.